# Flex-Grow and fitting evenly in container

Tags: html, css

I am making a calculator and am still working on the HTML and CSS. I am attempting to have my '=' sign take up two buttons worth and shrink the other 2 items in the row. I did this using flex-grow: 2 and it is almost exactly the size of the other two buttons but is about 4 pixels less. This is causing the last row to not be vertically aligned with the rows above it. How do I fix it so that flex-grow: 2 takes up exactly 2 times the size of each individual button?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="display">
                    <input type="text" name="display">
                </div>
                <div class="column1">
                    <input type="button" value="AC">
                    <input type="button" value="+/-">
                    <input type="button" value="%">
                    <input type="button" value="/">
                </div>
                <div class="column2">
                    <input type="button" value="7">
                    <input type="button" value="8">
                    <input type="button" value="9">
                    <input type="button" value="*">
                </div>
                <div class="column3">
                    <input type="button" value="4">
                    <input type="button" value="5">
                    <input type="button" value="6">
                    <input type="button" value="-">
                </div>
                <div class="column4">
                    <input type="button" value="1">
                    <input type="button" value="2">
                    <input type="button" value="3">
                    <input type="button" value="+">
                </div>
                <div class="column5">
                    <input type="button" class='single' value="0">
                    <input type="button" class='single' value=".">
                    <input type="button" class='double' value="=">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>

* {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 
.display input {
    background-color: rgb(207, 204, 204);
    display: flex;
}

.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5, .display {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.column1 input, .column2 input, .column3 input, .column4 input, .display input {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.column1 input, .column2 input, .column3 input, .column4 input, .column5 input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}

.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5 {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.column5 input {
    align-content: stretch;
}
 
.double {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.single {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    align-self:stretch;
}
```

Comment: This would be so much easier with Grid, which is designed for lining things up in both rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I thought flex worked well for everything

Comment: Nah, lining up in two directions is not great with flex unless every item is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment on your post, this is much better done with Grid, as it's designed to align items in rows and columns.

Here's a quick and dirty version of your layout with Grid (you can refine it to suit):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.container * {border: 1px solid black;}

form {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

input + input {border-radius: 6px;}

.display  {
  background-color: rgb(207, 204, 204);
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.double {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input class="display" type="text" name="display">
    <input type="button" value="AC">
    <input type="button" value="+/-">
    <input type="button" value="%">
    <input type="button" value="/">
    <input type="button" value="7">
    <input type="button" value="8">
    <input type="button" value="9">
    <input type="button" value="*">
    <input type="button" value="4">
    <input type="button" value="5">
    <input type="button" value="6">
    <input type="button" value="-">
    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="+">
    <input type="button" value="0">
    <input type="button" value=".">
    <input type="button" class='double' value="=">
  </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's much simpler with Grid, using less CSS and less HTML.